# how to enable HDFS file view in Ambari on hortonworks sandbox?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

how to enable HDFS file view in Ambari on hortonworks sandbox ?
I logged in with admin user.
I tried using admin->Manage view
 but I count not found any where file system view or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

It does not directly answer your question, but should be able to view the HDFS filesystem at [ambari.host]:50070/explorer.html#/

To  enable the HDFS file view in Ambari, the steps are well described in the Hortonworks documentation : you need to change the HDFS configuration, and then add a files view instance. Have a look here : http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_ambari_views_guide/content/ch_using_files_view.html

Answer (score 1):

Ambari Files View is one of the views shipped by Ambari 2.1.0 in the IOP 4.1 release. The View provides a web user interface for browsing HDFS, create/remove directories, downloading/uploading files, etc. The cluster must have HDFS and WebHDFS deployed in order to use the Ambari Files View.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading Hortonworks Sandbox HDP after 13 jun 2019 please go through this website https://www.roseindia.net/bigdata/hadoop/install-hortonworks-sandbox-on-virtualbox.shtml  and make sure you are downloading current version of Sandbox HDP(Now 3.1 version is available for sandbox) and VirtualBox 6.0 is present so make sure you are downloading both of above mentioned ..
This worked for me..